# Flutter FCM Ios not showing on device

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have add fcm in my application and all things but i can see notification body in my xcode console but in device its not showing also try in foreground mode not working.

I add FirebaseDelegateProxyEnabled in my info.plist

[image]

I have added background mode and push notification

[image]

Even i have added APNs Authentication Key But still is not working. I don't know what is remaining i can see my notification in console but why its not showing in device i even i try to minimize the app

[image]

Here is my console its showing notification data

```
2021-07-08 17:21:54.566047+0500 Runner[30106:10113438] flutter: on message {from: 110426208872, collapse_key: com.igidrive, notification: {e: 1, body: test again 123}}
```

Comment: Are you requesting for push notification permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue a week ago

I don't see your code here for the app delegate.

You can please verify did you add the below code in your **AppDelegate.swift** if not then please add.

```
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>) self;
 }
```

Also, make sure you are asking user permission

```
myFirebaseMessagingService.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
```

Change this line in your info.plist

```
 FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: false
```

**If everything is good then uninstall the app and try again installing this works some time.**

Comment: Ah i didn't ask for permission.